# NHibernate <timestamp> mapping for Oracle database causes StaleStateException

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, timestamp, optimistic-locking

We have an NHibernate app that we are migrating from SQL Server to Oracle. Our optimistic concurrency is implemented via a `<timestamp name="Version">` mapping element.

The data type of the corresponding `Version` column in Oracle is `DATE`. After we save an object, the in-memory C# object is left with a timestamp value in milliseconds (e.g. 12:34:56.789) while the value in the database is precise only to the second (e.g. 12:34:56). Thus, if we attempt to save the object a 2nd time, we get a StaleStateException because the two values do not match.

I attempted to fix this by altering the data type of the `Version` column to `TIMESTAMP(3)`. Unfortunately, the C# object and the DB value are still off by one millisecond (e.g. 12:34:56.789 vs 12:34:56.788), so the 2nd attempt to save the object still causes a StaleStateException.

What can I do to create a working `<timestamp>` mapping to an Oracle column of type `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` so that the same object can be saved multiple times?

Thanks.

-- Brian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TIMESTAMP(7) has the correct precision to match the .NET DateTime class and fixed the problem.

Comment: I have NHibernate code first. Type "Timestamp" generates an oracle field of type TIMESTAMP(4). How can I make it generate TIMESTAMP(7)?